# MongoEngine map_reduce merge collections

Tags: python, mongodb, mapreduce, mongoengine

I am using the MongoEngine map_reduce functionality in python.

According to the MongoDB documentation located [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce#MapReduce-Overview), it is possible to specify the way reduced data is handled. Specifically, it is possible to provide an argument to either "Replace," "Merge," "Reduce," or perform the mapping/reduction "inline."

I am unable to find instructions on how to specify similar parameters to the MongoEngine map_reduce function. The documentation for the function can be found [here](http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apireference.html).

Could someone explain how I could merge the results of a map_reduce operation into an already existing collection? I cannot perform the map_reduce operation inline.

I am using the following code to perform the map_reduce operation:

```
map_f = """
    #javascript code
"""

reduce_f = """
    #javascript code
"""

for i in FOO.objects.map_reduce(map_f, reduce_f, "FOOResult"):
    pass
```

Above, "FOOResult" is a new collection where a specific key will be overwritten each time the mapreduce operation occurs. I would much rather specify something that will allow me insert the same key into a collection that already exists.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I feel a bit silly for not recognizing this.

Solution:

```
for i in FOO.objects.map_reduce(map_f, reduce_f, {"merge":"COLLECTION_NAME"}):
    pass
```

Comment: Good work - please mark as answered to help others and if you have time add a ticket to http://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine suggesting the docs are made clearer :)

Comment: Thanks! I just added an issue ticket. I will mark the solution as solved, but I have to wait 48 hours before doing so (apparently that is stack-overflow policy?)